# How can I improve this Clojure function?

Tags: clojure

I just wrote my first Clojure function based on my very limited knowledge of the language. I would love some feedback in regards to performance and use of types. For example, I'm not sure 
if I should be using lists or vectors.

```
(defn actor-ids-for-subject-id [subject-id]
  (sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
    (sql/with-query-results results
      ["SELECT actor_id FROM entries WHERE subject_id = ?" subject-id]
      (let [res (into [] results)]
        (map (fn [row] (get row :actor_id)) res)))))
```

It passes the following test (given proper seed data):

```
(deftest test-actor-ids-for-subject-id
  (is (= ["123" "321"] (actor-ids-for-subject-id "123"))))
```

If it makes a difference (and I imagine it does) my usage characteristics of the returned data will almost exclusively involve generating the union and intersection of another set returned by the same function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's slightly more concise to use 'vec' instead of 'into' when the initial vector is empty. it may express the intent more clearly, though that's more a matter of preference.

```
(vec (map :actor_id results))
```

Answer (score 2):

the `results` is a `clojure.lang.Cons`, is lazy sequence, return by `clojure.java.jdbc/resultset-seq`. each record is a `map`:

```
(defn actor-ids-for-subject-id [subject-id]
  (sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
    (sql/with-query-results results
      ["SELECT actor_id FROM entries WHERE subject_id = ?" subject-id]
      (into [] (map :actor_id results)))))
```

Comment: Any reason you chose to return a vector instead of a list?

Comment: vector is better than list, no need quote, recommend it.

Comment: This is mostly an argument for literals. For anything generated it doesn't really matter. The only reason to convert something to a vector is when you need the specific characteristics of a vector. In this case it is pre-mature optimisation.